# Hot and Cold Binary Search Game

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Hot or cold.

I think you have to do some sort of binary search but I'm not sure how.

> Your goal is the guess a secret integer between 1 and N. You
>   repeatedly guess integers between 1 and N. After each guess you learn
>   if it equals the secret integer (and the game stops); otherwise
>   (starting with the second guess), you learn if the guess is hotter
>   (closer to) or colder (farther from) the secret number than your
>   previous guess. Design an algorithm that finds the secret number in lg
>   N + O(1) guesses.
>
> Hint: Design an algorithm that solves the problem in lg N + O(1)
>   guesses assuming you are permitted to guess integers in the range -N
>   to 2N.

I've been racking my brain and I can't seem to come up with a a lg N + O(1).

I found this: http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_cs;action=display;num=1316188034 but could not understand the diagram and it did not describe other possible cases.

Comment: What is your algorithm? A simple binary search would achieve this...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15678789/427252 ??

Comment: We can't use a normal binary search approach we would end up making 2*lg N queries every time we want to cut the interval in half instead of the lg N queries.

In that SO question you linked, what do we do after the third guess? It doesn't quite say in the top answer.

Comment: Because if the base isn't specified, any multiplicative constant can be absorbed into the base...

Comment: A slightly more explicit version of the hint is that, if you know that the number is in the range [a, b], and you make consecutive guesses less than a and greater than b in some order, then hot/cold tells you whether the number is over some threshold.

Comment: Yeah.  I actually think the hint gets you only a small part of the way to the solution.  The "end case" is considerably screwier.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you know that your secret integer is in `[a,b]`, and that your last guess is `c`.

You want to divide your interval by two, and to know whether your secret integer lies in between `[a,m]` or `[m,b]`, with `m=(a+b)/2`.

The trick is to guess `d`, such that `(c+d)/2 = (a+b)/2`.

Without loss of generality, we can suppose that `d` is bigger than `c`. Then, if `d` is hotter than `c`, your secret integer will be bigger than `(c+d)/2 = (a+b)/2 = m`, and so your secret integer will lie in `[m,b]`. If `d` is cooler than `c`, your secret integer will belong to `[a,m]`.

You need to be able to guess between `-N` and `2N` because you can't guarantee that `c` and `d` as defined above will always be `[a,b]`. Your two first guess can be `1` and `N`.

So, your are dividing your interval be two at each guess, so the complexity is log(N) + O(1).

A short example to illustrate this (results chosen randomly):

```
Guess    Result    Interval of the secret number
 1       ***       [1   , N    ]    // d    =  a   +  b  - c
 N       cooler    [1   , N/2  ]    // N    =  1   +  N  - 1
-N/2     cooler    [N/4 , N/2  ]    //-N/2  =  1   + N/2 - N
 5N/4    hotter    [3N/8, N/2  ]    // 5N/4 = N/4  + N/2 + N/2
-3N/8    hotter    [3N/8, 7N/16]    //-3N/8 = 3N/8 + N/2 - 5N/4
  .        .            .               .
  .        .            .               .
  .        .            .               .
```

---

Edit, suggested by @tmyklebu:

We still need to prove that our guess will always fall in bewteen `[-N,2N]`

By recurrence, suppose that `c` (our previous guess) is in `[a-(a+b), b+(a+b)] = [-b,a+2b]`

Then `d = a+b-c <= a+b-(-b) <= a+2b` and `d = a+b-c >= a+b-(a+2b) >= -b`

Initial case: `a=1, b=N, c=1`, `c` is indeed in `[-b,a+2*b]`

QED

Comment: You glossed over how to handle the case where your desired guess falls outside [1, N].  This is the key to the problem.

Comment: Your desired guess have to be in between [-N,2N]. You just need a simple recurrence to prove it, but you are right, I'll edit my post.

Comment: That's a relaxation of the problem.  The "end case" where you're trying to guess a number in `[1, K]` allowed only guesses in `[1, N]` also matters.

Comment: @tmyklebu Not according to awesome_dude3933 specifications. However, I would be keen to see a solution in lg N with this additional constraint.

Comment: `lg N` is unattainable.  I gave a solution that takes `lg N + 6` guesses in the worst case in my answer below.

Comment: lg N + O(1) was what I meant... But indeed, your answer is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This was a task at IOI 2010, for which I sat on the Host Scientific Committee.  (We asked for an optimal solution instead of simply `lg N + O(1)`, and what follows is not quite optimal.)

Not swinging outside `-N .. 2N` and using `lg N + 2` guesses is straightforward; all you need to do is show that the obvious translation of binary search works.

Once you have something that doesn't swing outside `-N .. 2N` and takes `lg N + 2` guesses, do this:

Guess `N/2`, then `N/2+1`. This tells you which half of the array the answer is in. Then guess the end of that half-array. You're either in one of the two "middle" quarters or you're in one of the two "end" quarters. If you're in a middle quarter, do the thing before and you win in `lg N + 4` guesses. The ends are slightly trickier.

Suppose I need to guess a number in `1 .. K` without straying outside `1 .. N` and my last guess was `1`. If I guess `K/2` and I'm colder, then I next guess 1; I spent two guesses to get a similar subproblem that's 1/4 the size. If `K/2` is hotter, I know the answer is in `K/4 .. K`. Guess `K/2-1` next. The two subcases are `K/4 .. K/2-1` and `K/2 .. K`, both of which are nice. But it took me three guesses to (in the worst-case) halve the size of the problem; if I ever do this, I wind up doing `lg N + 6` guesses.

Comment: _But it took me three guesses to (in the worst-case) halve the size of the problem_ In this case, your complexity is 3 lg(N) + O(1), since you need to do this each time you divide your problem (which will be the case if you have to guess 2 or N-1 for example)

Comment: @user3923424: No, I need to do that at most once, since before I'm in the "end" case and after I'm in the "middle" case, where I never have to do that again.  This does not change the coefficient of `lg N`.

Comment: What about guessing number 2? K/2 will always be colder than 1, except in the very last steps. I don't see at which point you will get in the "middle" case... (sorry to bother, I would like to understand)

Comment: @user3923424: The "middle-case" recursion is properly handled by your answer.  The "end-case" recursion uses two guesses to either quarter the size of the end or get a "middle-case" 3/4 the size of the end.  `K/2` will not always be colder than `1` since the answer could lie in `[K/4, K]`; it's only colder than `1` if we're staying in the end-case recursion.

Comment: Ok... I see how it's working now: you are still in the "end" case, but guessing `1` allows you to reduce your interval by 2 as well. Therefore, except for the extra initial guess (`1`) your are dividing your interval by 2 each time. With your words: you either divide by 4 the interval, or get a "middle" case using 2 guesses. Cheers then.

Comment: Reduce by 4, but it takes two guesses.

Comment: Sorry if it is a very bad question but I don't see the advantage of this algorithm. Doesn't binary search algorithm find the secret number in $\lgN + 1$ guess?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is close to binary search. At each step you have an interval that the number can be in. Start with the whole interval `[1, N]`. First guess both ends - that is the numbers `1` and `N`. One of them will be closer, thus you will know that now the number you are searching for is in `[1, N/2]` or in `[N/2 + 1, N]`(considering N even for simplicity). Now you go to the next step having a twice smaller interval. Continue using the same approach. Keep in mind that you've already probed one of the ends, however it may not be your last guess.

I am not sure what you mean by `lg N + O(1)`, but the approach I suggest will perform O(log(N)) operations and in the worst case it will do exactly log<sub>4</sub>(N) probes.

Comment: `lg N` is the base-two logarithm of N.  A function is O(1) if it is bounded above by a constant.

Comment: Hmm at least in the math I have studied lg(N) is base 10 logarithm, [not a base 2 logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11) I know what is O(1) very well, but as base 10 has nothing to do with the problem I have written: `am not sure what you mean by lg N + O(1)`

Comment: That's odd.  `lg N` means base-two logarithm everywhere I've seen.

Comment: @tmyklebu nope both ISO 31-11 and the superseding [ISO 80000-2](http://www.ise.ncsu.edu/jwilson/files/mathsigns.pdf) state otherwise.

Comment: That's bizarre!  Never seen `lb` and I've always seen `lg` for base-two log.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - in CS departments in the US logs are almost always assumed to be base 2. People are often sloppy on notation because a log in one base is equal to the log in another base to within a scaling constant, and scale constants are ignored with big O.

Comment: @pjs please note that here the log is **not** in a big O. Only the remainder is in big O notation. I assume this means that the number of operations is exactly lg(N) plus a constant.

Comment: @pjs: This problem is trivial if you take a base for your logarithm larger than 2.  And it's impossible if you take a base smaller than 2.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I'm fully aware of that.  I'm just trying to explain why 2 is the default thinking in CS departments over here.

Comment: @tmyklebu Yes, I know.  I'm the one who upvoted Oli Charlesworth's comment to the OP about that.

Comment: @pjs: Gotcha.  Thought you were trying to advocate for a half-assed solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Here're my two cents for this problem, since I got obsessed with it for two days. I'm not going to say anything new to what others have already said, but I'm going to explain it in a way that might get some people to understand the solution easily(or at least that was the way I managed to understand it).

Drawing from the ~ 2 lg N solution, if I knew that solution existed in `[a, b]` I'd want to know if it's in the left half `[a, (a + b) / 2]` or the right half `[(a + b) / 2, b]`, with the point `(a + b) / 2` separating the two halves. So what do I do? I guess `a` then `b`; if I get colder with `b` I know I'm in the first(left) half, if I get hotter I know I'm in the second(right) one. So guessing `a` and `b` is the way to know the secret integer position with respect to the mid point `(a + b) / 2`. However `a` and `b` aren't the only points that I can guess at to know the secret position. `(a - 1, b + 1)`, `(a - 2, b + 2)`, ... etc are all valid pairs of points to guess at to know the secret position, as the mid point of all these pairs is `(a + b) / 2`, the mid point of the original interval `[a, b]`. In fact any two numbers `c` and `d` such that `(c + d) / 2 = (a + b) / 2` can be used.

So considering `[a, b]` as the interval we know the secret integer exists within, take `c` to be the last number we guessed. We want to determine the position of the secret with respect to the mid point `(a + b) / 2`, so we a new number `d` to guess at to know the secret relative position to `(a + b) / 2`. How do we know such number `d`? By solving the equation `(c + d) / 2 = (a + b) / 2`, which yields `d = a + b - c`. Guessing at that `d`, we shrink the range `[a, b]` appropriately based on the answer(colder or hotter) and then repeat the process taking `d` as our last guess and trying a new guess at number `e` for example with the same conditions.

To establish the initial conditions, we should start with `a = 1`, `b = N`, and `c = 1`. We guess at `c` to establish a reference(since the first guess can't tell you anything useful as there were no prior guesses). We then proceed with new guesses and adjusting the enclosing interval as appropriate with each guess. The table in [@R2B2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25567960/493119) explains it all.

You have to be vigilant however when trying to code this solution. When I tried to code it in [python](https://gist.github.com/MSK61/1997c31e01fafbaff01f), I first ran into the mistake of getting `[a, b]` stuck when it was small enough(like `[a, a + 1]`) where neither `a` nor `b` would move inwards. I had to phase the cases where the interval size was 2 outside the loop and handle them separately(like I did with intervals with size 1 also).

Answer (score 0):

the task is quite brain cracking
but I'll try to keep it simple

1. to solve the problem in 2lnN let's make following guesses:
   1 and N : to decide which half is hotter (1, N/2) or (N/2, N), for example (N/2, N) is the hotter half, then let's make next guesses
   N/2 and N : again to decide which half is hotter (N/2, 3/4N) or (3/4N, N) and so on
   ... so we need 2 guesses for every half-division, therefore we should make 2 * lnN guesses.
   here we see that each time we need to repeat one of previous intervals' borders one more time - in our example point 'N' is repeated.
2. to solve the problem in 1*lnN guesses instead of 2*lnN, we need to find way to spend only one guess for each intervals' half-division, good illustration of such method is depicted on image at http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_cs;action=display;num=1316188034
   the idea is to avoid repeating one of border points of each interval again in subsequent steps, but be smart to spend one guess for each half-division step by mirroring points.
   the smart idea is that when we want to decide which half of current interval is hotter, we don't need to try only its borders, but we can as well try any points located outside its borders, these guessing points must be at equal distances (in other words mirrored) relatively to the center of interesting interval, nothing bad even if these guessing points are negative (i.e. < 0) or if they are > N (this is not prohibited by the conditions of the task)
   so to guess the secret we can freely make guesses using pounts in interval (-N, 2N)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HotOrCold {
    static int num=5000;// number to search
    private static int prev=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(guess(1,Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        
    }
    public static int guess(int lo,int hi) {
        while(hi>=lo) {
            boolean one=false;
            boolean two=false;
            if(hi==lo) {
                return lo;
            }
            if(isHot(lo)) {
                one=true;
            }
            if(isHot(hi)) {
                two=true;
            }
            if(!(one||two)) {
                return (hi+lo)/2;// equal distance
            }
            if(two) {
                lo=hi-(hi-lo)/2;
                continue;//checking two before as it's hotter than lo so ignoring the lo
            }
            if(one) {
                hi=lo+(hi-lo)/2;
            }
            
        }
        
        return 0;
        
    }

    public static boolean isHot(int curr) {
        boolean hot=false;
        if(Math.abs(num-curr)<Math.abs(num-prev)) {
            hot=true;
        }
        prev=curr;
        return hot;
    }
}
```